# Conditional based where condition in sequelize Node JS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to execute a query in sequelize, in which the where conditions have to be added based on the request parameters

```
router.get("/getsearchdata",(req, res) => {
    var searchquery =[
        {model:ProvidersCategories,attributes:["category_id"],
        include: [
            {model:Categories,attributes:["category_id","category_name"]},
        ]
        }
        ]  


    if(req.query.agency && req.query.agency!=''){
        searchquery.where = {
        $and: [
        {agencyName: {$like: '%' + req.query.agency + '%'}},
        ]
    }
    }


    Providers.findAll({
        include:searchquery
    }).then(providerData =>{
        if(!providerData) {
        res.status(404).send({reason:'no data found'});
        } else {
        res.status(200).send(providerData);
        }
    });
    });
```

I have three tables "providers", "categories" and "provider_Categories". I am trying to join the three tables and get the providers.
In the request i.e req, if there is an input `req.query.agency != ''` then an if condition has to added `where agencyName like "% + req.query.agency + %"`, if input `req.query.agency == ''` then there should be no if condition. For which I have tried the above code. But the where condition is not getting concatenated to the main query even if there is input `req.query.agency`

What is the right way to write where conditionally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `searchquery` is an array and you can't assign a `where` property to it. What you should do, is just passing a `where` object to the query options object:

```
    router.get("/getsearchdata", (req, res) => {
        var whereClause;

        if (req.query.agency && req.query.agency != '') {
            whereClause = {agencyName: {$like: '%' + req.query.agency + '%'}};
        }


        Providers.findAll({
            include: [
                {
                    model: ProvidersCategories, attributes: ["category_id"],
                    include: [
                        {model: Categories, attributes: ["category_id", "category_name"]},
                    ]
                }
            ],
            where: whereClause
        }).then(providerData => {
            if (!providerData) {
                res.status(404).send({reason: 'no data found'});
            } else {
                res.status(200).send(providerData);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: The solution is working fine but I am trying to add one more if condition if (req.query.insurance && req.query.insurance != '') {
            whereClause = whereClause+{'ProviderCategories->Category`.`category_name' : req.query.category};
        } and it is giving the error as Unhandled rejection Error: Support for `{where: 'raw query'}` has been removed.

Comment: Since `whereClause` is an object and not a string, you need to use it's properties and not just appending strings. If I understood you correcly, you need something like:  `whereClause['ProviderCategories->Category.category_name'] = req.query.category;`

Comment: But if you want to apply a condition to a Category object, you should define a separate variable, and pass it to the `where` attribute inside Category: `var categoryWhereClause = {category_name: req.query.category};` `... {model: Categories, attributes: ["category_id", "category_name"], where: categoryWhereClause},`

Comment: And if your query have empty parameter? I need to do one query with and without "where" condition.